# Not stable loading of local HTML/JS files in WebView (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I have troubles in the following setup:

- MainActivity implements a full screen WebView which runs locally loaded files from /assets - works fine
- I open second activity as popup, again with WebView in it which uses the same local files (just with different parameters)

Problem: the webview in popup loads properly like 1 out of 3 tries. Scripts do not find document.body and that's all. You just try again in a couple of seconds and it works - quite unstable but I do not understand why?

Comment: put up the code what you have tried

Comment: sorry, cannot put up all the code (NDA violation), finding it hard to choose which small snipped to take

Comment: have you tried : 

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: Yes, the web app is quite rich with a number of scripts and HTMLs and CSS whatever. It works, generally, just load is not stable

Answer (score 0):

Root cause found: at the times of failure the dom model was still not ready, when JS code started. Related script code has been located straight in included .js file, so the time point when it was executed was not controlled by us, but by webview implementation. We added syncornization on document.readyState and all worked